# selecting specific occurrences from a group SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ranking-functions

Data set looks like

```
id    statusid    statusdate    
100    22         04/12/2016    
100    22         04/14/2016
100    25         04/16/2016
100    25         04/17/2016
100    25         04/19/2016
100    22         04/22/2016
100    22         05/14/2016
100    27         05/19/2016
100    27         06/14/2016
100    25         06/18/2016
100    22         07/14/2016
100    22         07/18/2016
```

Task is to select the First time each status was logged. Number of unique times each status were logged.

Example :
For Status 22

- First time status date: 04/12/2016
- Last time Status first date: 07/14/2016
- Number of Unique times it went to that status: 3

Comment: Hint:  `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: So, why is it a problem? Have you ever written any aggregation queries?

Comment: Please explain your logic for `Number of Unique times`.

Comment: pls. add some sample data & desired output which could help other to answer the question.

Comment: Thats the sample date in the question.. and the below queries i have mentioned the issue i am facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is complicated than it looks. I assume you want the unique consecutive times for a given status.
Use a difference of row numbers approach to classify consecutive rows into groups. Then get the row numbers in those groups. Finally aggregate to get the first day in the first and last group and the number of distinct groups.

```
select statusid
,max(case when rn_grp_asc=1 then statusdate end) as last_time_first_status
,max(case when rn_grp_desc=1 then statusdate end) as last_time_first_status
,count(distinct grp) as unique_times_in_status
from (select t.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by statusid order by grp,statusdate) as rn_grp_asc 
      ,row_number() over(partition by statusid order by grp desc,statusdate) as rn_grp_desc
      from (select t.*,row_number() over(order by statusdate)
           -row_number() over(partition by statusid order by statusdate) as grp
            from tbl t
           ) t
      ) t
group by statusid
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This almost gives the result I wanted. But the aggregation on number of unique values comes out wrong if ID is included in the a group by.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  ID,
        statusid,
        Status,
        max(case when rn_grp_asc=1 then statusdate end) as frst_time_first_status,
        max(case when rn_grp_desc=1 then statusdate end) as last_time_first_status,
        count(distinct grp) as unique_times_in_status
from    (   select  t.*,
                    row_number() over(partition by id,statusid order by grp,statusdate) as rn_grp_asc,
                    row_number() over(partition by id,statusid order by grp desc,statusdate) as rn_grp_desc
            from    (   Select  ID,
                                StatusID,
                                Status,
                                StatusDate,
                                row_number() over(partition by id order by Systemdate)-row_number() over(partition by id,statusid order by Systemdate) as grp
                       from     t
                      where ID=100
           ) t
      ) t
group by id,statusid,Status
```

Above query returns the correct results, but the following query does not.

```
select  ID,
        statusid,
        Status,
        max(case when rn_grp_asc=1 then statusdate end) as frst_time_first_status,
        max(case when rn_grp_desc=1 then statusdate end) as last_time_first_status,
        count(distinct grp) as unique_times_in_status
from    (   select  t.*,
                    row_number() over(partition by id,statusid order by grp,statusdate) as rn_grp_asc,
                    row_number() over(partition by id,statusid order by grp desc,statusdate) as rn_grp_desc
            from    (   Select  ID,
                                StatusID,
                                Status,
                                StatusDate,
                                row_number() over(partition by id order by Systemdate)-row_number() over(partition by id,statusid order by Systemdate) as grp
                       from     t    
         ) t
) t
 where  ID=100
group by id,statusid,Status
```